# Jira task hierarchies

Tags: jira

Searching online, I see lots of people asking for features to have multiple levels of sub-tasks, and proper sub-task functionality (like FogBugz). But I don't know if it's planned in future versions, or if plugins exist to provide this functionality.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4):

we're working on a plug-in for multi-level subtasks. See details and follow us at http://h4j.almworks.com

As for current solutions, you may use links as a very limited workaround. There are also some hacks to allow creation of sub-sub-tasks, see comments to http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-4446

**Update:** the add-on has been released in 2011 and went far beyond just multiple hierarchy levels. Currently it's at version 4 and it's one of the most popular add-ons for JIRA. See https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.almworks.jira.structure/server/overview

Comment: Why dead? It's called Structure now and beta version have been released - https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/34717